# Why do I get "unexpected tIDENTIFIER" syntax error in Chef recipe?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

This cookbook recipe has a syntax error, but I don't understand why. I cannot upload the cookbook.

```
#below reference information we saw in ohai

    if node[“platform”] == “ubuntu”
    execute “apt-get update” do 
      command “apt-get update”
    end
    end

    package "apache2" do 
      action :install
    end

    # Start the apache service and add to bootup (scripts)
    #service directive below

    service "apache2" do 
      action [:start, :enable]
    end

    > #knife cookbook upload apache Uploading apache
         [0.1.1] FATAL: Cookbook file  has a ruby syntax error
: FATAL:
    > /home/fice/git/chef-repo/cookbooks/apache/recipes/install.rb:8: syntax
    > error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    > FATAL: execute “apt-get update” do  FATAL:                            
    > ^ FATAL:
    > /home/fice/git/chef-repo/cookbooks/apache/recipes/install.rb:9: syntax
    > error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    > FATAL:
    > /home/fice/git/chef-repo/cookbooks/apache/recipes/install.rb:24:
    > syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
```

Comment: Did you happen to copy and paste the code from somewhere? It looks like you have weird quotations on `if node[“platform”] == “ubuntu”
    execute “apt-get update” do 
      command “apt-get update”
    end
    end`. Try manually replacing the `"` in that code and see if it fixes it.

Comment: I have another recipe that contained this code in sublime. I copied and pasted the if section into this recipe. Inserting the correct double quotes fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems as if you copied some of the code from another source which may include curly quotes in your code which is not recognized by the parser.

Please replace the “ characters in the following code with `"`

```
if node[“platform”] == “ubuntu”
execute “apt-get update” do 
  command “apt-get update”
end
end
```

Comment: There were no curly braces.  I retyped the entire recipe with the correct double quotes. The cookbook uploaded. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Omit the "There were no curly braces" in my last response. :)